# Add compiled class files to classpath for import in java gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, classpath

I have a java project with gradle. How to import external compiled class files (.class) into this project to use them. Like adding compiled class files to classpath. with javac i just do javac -cp .  somefile.java. I am new with gradle so can someone give me solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is never recommended to add class files in this manner, but it does not stop from doing so

`compileJava.classpath = compileJava.classpath + files(file("$project.rootDir/lib"))`

Comment: so which block should i add these. And how is it different from implementation files('path/to/dir/container/classfiles').

Comment: it does not need to be in any block.